# How can I display name in single contact flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, kotlin, dart

I have a list of contact name with permission handler and I would like to get the name for every contact in single contact page

Here's What I've so far, but I'm getting an error

```dart
import 'package:contacts_service/contacts_service.dart';
import 'package:elraydeon1/screens.dart/individualpage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

class ContactFetch extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String screenroute = "ContactFetch";
  const ContactFetch({super.key});

  get displayName => null;
  get phones => null;

  @override
  State<ContactFetch> createState() => _ContactState();
}

class _ContactState extends State<ContactFetch> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _askPermissions();
  }

  Future<void> _askPermissions() async {
    PermissionStatus permissionStatus = await _getContactPermission();
    if (permissionStatus != PermissionStatus.granted) {
      _handleInvalidPermissions(permissionStatus);
    }
  }

  Future<PermissionStatus> _getContactPermission() async {
    PermissionStatus permission = await Permission.contacts.status;
    if (permission != PermissionStatus.granted &&
        permission != PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied) {
      PermissionStatus permissionStatus = await Permission.contacts.request();
      return permissionStatus;
    } else {
      return permission;
    }
  }

  void _handleInvalidPermissions(PermissionStatus permissionStatus) {
    if (permissionStatus == PermissionStatus.denied) {
      const snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text('Access to contact data denied'));
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
    } else if (permissionStatus == PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied) {
      const snackBar =
          SnackBar(content: Text('Contact data not available on device'));
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
    }
  }

  Future<List<Contact>>? reqContact;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Contacts List'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  reqContact =
                      ContactsService.getContacts() as Future<List<Contact>>?;
                });
              },
              child: const Text("Load Contact")),
          Expanded(
              child: FutureBuilder(
                  future: reqContact,
                  builder: (context, snp) {
                    if (snp.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                      var contacts = snp.data;

                      if (contacts != null) {
                        return ListView.builder(
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            itemCount: contacts.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              Contact contact = contacts[index];

                              return ListTile(
                                title: Text(' ${contact.displayName}'),
                                leading: CircleAvatar(
                                  child: Text("A"),
                                ),
                                subtitle: Text(contact.phones?.single.value ??
                                    "not found"),
                                onTap: () {
                                  Navigator.pushNamed(
                                      context, Individualpage.screenroute);
                                },
                              );
                            });
                      }
                      return Container();
                    }
                    return Container();
                  })),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```dart
import 'package:contacts_service/contacts_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Individualpage extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String screenroute = "IndividualPage";
  const Individualpage({super.key});

  @override
  State<Individualpage> createState() => _IndividualpageState();
}

class _IndividualpageState extends State<Individualpage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      leading: CircleAvatar(
        child: Text("A"),
      ),
      title: Text("${Contact(displayName: )}"),//error
    ));
  }
}
```

Then this is the error I'm getting.

```dart
title: Text("${Contact(displayName: )}")
```

Comment: What's the error that you're getting?

Comment: when i clicked on first name in list of contact i transferred to the single contact page, in AppBar in single contact contain photo of person ,name and last seen how can i show the name of contact(display name) in AppBar when i clicked on name of person in  list

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are facing issue in sending data from one screen to other screen in flutter.
You can pass data via arguments while routing to **Individualpage** like :

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
          Individualpage.screenroute,
          arguments: {
            'title':'${contact.displayName}'
          });  //pass arguments with routing
```

and now on target page you can get the arguments like this :

```
import 'package:contacts_service/contacts_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class Individualpage extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String screenroute = "IndividualPage";
  const Individualpage({super.key});



  @override
  State<Individualpage> createState() => _IndividualpageState();
}

class _IndividualpageState extends State<Individualpage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {



final routesArguments=ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as Map<String,String>;  //get route arguments
        return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          leading: CircleAvatar(
            child: Text("A"),
          ),
          title: Text("${routesArguments['title']}"),//get value from route arguments
        ));
      }
    }
```

and similarly you can pass more values in json with Navigator.of(context).pushNamed function.

Comment: thanks ,but title line in individual page gives me error like this ((Undefined name 'routes Arguments'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.dart))  I written the routes Arguments right what can I do ?

Comment: use 'widget.' to access variables declared in stateful class, I have updated the same in answer.

Comment: thanks @MANISH but show to me another error ((Error: Undefined name 'context'.
 final routes Arguments = ModalRoute.of(context as BuildContext)) what can I do? and thanks you for caring

Comment: @AbdelrahmanHashem can you try the solution now, I have updated the required block of code

Comment: thanks, but gives me another error in this line(title: Text("${routesArguments['title']}"), show to this message (Undefined name 'routesArguments'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.) what can I do????

Comment: @AbdelrahmanHashem can you share screenshot of error

Comment: [link](https://ibb.co/2yfJCWJ)

Comment: @AbdelrahmanHashem in your code at line number 15 you need to rename your variable as "routesArguments" as given in the answer

Comment: Hi@MANISH, second question , I want to load the contact list I need this list when I pressed on load contact this list upload to firebase

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are thinking in right direction but there is minor changes in your implementation.

- First when you pass the arguments in pushNamed give named parameter arguments in that and pass your data..

```
class ContactFetch extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String screenroute = "ContactFetch";
  const ContactFetch({super.key});

  get displayName => null;
  get phones => null;

  @override
  State<ContactFetch> createState() => _ContactState();
}

class _ContactState extends State<ContactFetch> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _askPermissions();
  }

  Future<void> _askPermissions() async {
    PermissionStatus permissionStatus = await _getContactPermission();
    if (permissionStatus != PermissionStatus.granted) {
      _handleInvalidPermissions(permissionStatus);
    }
  }

  Future<PermissionStatus> _getContactPermission() async {
    PermissionStatus permission = await Permission.contacts.status;
    if (permission != PermissionStatus.granted &&
        permission != PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied) {
      PermissionStatus permissionStatus = await Permission.contacts.request();
      return permissionStatus;
    } else {
      return permission;
    }
  }

  void _handleInvalidPermissions(PermissionStatus permissionStatus) {
    if (permissionStatus == PermissionStatus.denied) {
      const snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text('Access to contact data denied'));
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
    } else if (permissionStatus == PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied) {
      const snackBar =
          SnackBar(content: Text('Contact data not available on device'));
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
    }
  }

  Future<List<Contact>>? reqContact;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Contacts List'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  reqContact =
                      ContactsService.getContacts() as Future<List<Contact>>?;
                });
              },
              child: const Text("Load Contact")),
          Expanded(
              child: FutureBuilder(
                  future: reqContact,
                  builder: (context, snp) {
                    if (snp.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                      var contacts = snp.data;

                      if (contacts != null) {
                        return ListView.builder(
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            itemCount: contacts.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              Contact contact = contacts[index];

                              return ListTile(
                                title: Text(' ${contact.displayName}'),
                                leading: CircleAvatar(
                                  child: Text("A"),
                                ),
                                subtitle: Text(contact.phones?.single.value ??
                                    "not found"),
                                onTap: () {
                                  Navigator.pushNamed(
                                      context,Individualpage.screenroute ,arguments: {'contact': contact});
                                },
                              );
                            });
                      }
                      return Container();
                    }
                    return Container();
                  })),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

- Now in your single contact page you need to fetch your arguments...

```
import 'package:contacts_service/contacts_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Individualpage extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String screenroute = "IndividualPage";
  const Individualpage({super.key});

  @override
  State<Individualpage> createState() => _IndividualpageState();
}

class _IndividualpageState extends State<Individualpage> {
    late Contact contact;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final arg = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments;
        if(arg is Map){
      if((arg).containsKey('contact')){
        contact = arg as Contact;
      }
    }
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      leading: CircleAvatar(
        child: Text("A"),
      ),
      title: Text("${contact.displayName}"),//error
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but in this line ` Navigator.pushNamed(
                                      context ,arguments: {Individualpage.screenroute}:contact);` ,gives me error (2 positional arguments expected by 'push Named', but 1 found.
Try adding the missing arguments.) what can I Do??

Comment: @AbdelrahmanHashem I updated my answer. And I just need to confirm that when you doing pushNamed you are navigate to that page? If yes, then this logic works perfect..

Comment: Thanks , but show to me another two error first, ((The instance member 'context' can't be accessed in an initializer.
Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression)) this in line of (final arg) and second error is ((Expected a class member.
Try placing this code inside a class member)) in line of if statement if (arg is map) ,what can I do? thank you for caring

Comment: Now @AbdelrahmanHashem check it. This works or not?

Comment: thanks , gives me error in line(contact=arg) error in arg gives me (A value of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Contact'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'Contact'.)

Comment: Hey, @AbdelrahmanHashem answer is updated please check it.